# Bashスクリプト内で "=" の前後にスペースがある時にエラーが出ない理由

Tags: bash

Bashのスクリプトで代入する時にうっかり

```
foo = "bar"
```

のように`=`の前後にスペースを入れて書いてしまったのですが、`foo`に何も代入されないだけでエラーが起きませんでした。

インタラクティブなbashシェル上で同じ記述をすると

```
bash: foo: command not found
```

のエラーになりますが、何が原因でスクリプト中ではエラーを吐かないんでしょうか？

Comment: こちらの環境(※)で試してみましたが、エラーメッセージが表示されます。
./q2.sh: line 1: foo: command not found
※　GNU bash, バージョン 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
お使いのbashのバージョン、実行したスクリプト全体の内容が分かれば原因がわかるかもしれません。

Comment: 再度確認した所、変数名にコマンドとして存在するものを使っていたためエラーが出なかったようです。質問する際に必要な情報が抜け落ちてしまっていました申し訳ありません。

Answer (score 0):

質問では`foo`という変数名を書いたのですが、

エラーが出なかった環境では変数名に`basename`というコマンドとして存在する名前を使っていたため
`command not found`のエラーが出ずに代入行以降は空白の文字列の入った変数として扱われていたようでした。

質問文になかった情報を含んでしまっていますが質問を閉じるために回答を投稿いたしました。

Comment: 空白の入った変数ではなくて単なる `argv` っすね。 `echo = "abc"` で試すと理解しやすいと思うっす。

Comment: なるほど、まだ勘違いしてました。ありがとうございます。代入処理のあとに`echo $basename`で何も出力されなかったので空白で初期化されたのかと思ってたのですが、bashは未定義の変数でもエラーを出さないのを忘れてました。

Answer (score 0):

bashにて代入する時にスペースがいらないです。一行一行実行しますので、foo = "bar"と書くと、footコマンドを実行して、=と"bar"は引数となります。fooコマンドがないと、command not foundのエラーが出ます。
ls -la ./  のような形です。もし、lsをsdfsdfsdfで変わると、sdfsdfsdf -la ./ 同じで、command not foundのエラーが出るはずです。